# Make a rectangular border around the multiline text

Tags: html, css

I have an html tag like this:

```
<pre>
  <b style="border: 1px dotted #999;">      Expected true to be false.
      here some content.
</b>
</pre>
```

I expect the text to be in a box, of course it does, but it collapse as its in multi line. As like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/40c5vhvc/).

Where I'm making mistake? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mistake: `b` is a natural inline element. If you apply a border to an inline element the result you achieve is a border applied to every line

You can change its display property, e.g. use `display: inline-block;`

```
<b style="border: 1px dotted #999; display: inline-block">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5s3vxbv3/

Result

[image]

---

Alternatively, if you need to outline just the text then use the `outline` property

```
<b style="outline: 1px dotted #999;">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5xc5ef1x/

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works. But does this `display: inline-block` does? And how it solves the issue?

Comment: And what should I do to make the box starts from the text only?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/5xc5ef1x/2/You can also do in this way too.

```
<pre style="border: 1px dotted #999;float:left; ">
  <b>            Expected true to be false.
      here some content.
</b>
</pre>
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/5xc5ef1x/2/